# URL Rewriting.htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a URL through htaccess, but I am not getting the solution to do the specific rewriting. For e.g., I have a URL:

**http://www.yourdomain.com/page/about-us.html**

Now I want to remove **page** from above URL, so it should look like;

**http://www.yourdomain.com/about-us.html**

Can anybody help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us.html$ /page/about-us.html
```

If you need it done on any URL put into the site, then something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([_\&\'\,\+A-Za-z0-9-]+).html$ /page/$1.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a 301:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^page/about-us.html$ /about.html [R=301,L]
```